# Software License question

Tags: licensing, github

I am building some software which I am storing on Github (public).

Is it possible to change the license so that I can sell my software at some later point in time, as long as no one has contributed to my project?

I am fine for people to see or use my code, but when it gets to a critical point I want to pull it from Github and just have my own product which I can do as I please.

Comment: Might also be a duplicate of **[How do I dual license?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/114945/22815)**.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** and **no**.

If you change the license on Github, then anyone who grabs that copy of your software is bound to the new license. The caveat is that anyone who had previously grabbed a copy of your source code are bound to the **old** license.

If you have an idea of which license or restrictions you want to place, it would be better to do it now. It's less of a headache going from a restrictive license to a less-restrictive license than the other way around.